# Proof using Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Give the induction proof of:

$$
1.2 + 2.3 + k(k+1) = \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}
$$

Is this proof even possible? Not sure how to do.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, of course. What have you done so far?

Comment: well the base case using a=3 works because 20=20, now im assuming you put k+1 in for all ks

Comment: The way it's written down it only holds for $k=3$... But yes you can prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to prove that if
$$1\cdot 2+2\cdot3 \cdots+k(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}$$
holds, then
$$1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+\cdots+k(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}$$
now you must show that
$$\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}+(k+1)(k+2)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}$$

Comment: how did you get k(k+1)(k+2)/3 at the bottom there, where did it come from?

Comment: this comes from the first equation

Comment: okay so I have (k(k+1)(k+2) + (k+1)(k+2))/3 on the left side, how can I manipulate that to get to the right side?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = \frac13 n(n+1)(n+2)$$
Now the base case $n=1$ reads $1\cdot 2 = 2 = \frac13 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$. For the induction step, try something and comment where you get stuck.

Comment: so then by induction you need to show summnation (k+1)(k+2)=1/3(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)    correct? @AlexR